# How to call a function once per thread

Tags: c++, c++11

How to be sure that a function/method will be called only once per thread?

I have a function that is called periodically and it has to call an Init method only once in the same thread. But if this function is called by another thread it has to do the Init for this new thread but again, only once.

Is there a mechanism to perform this?
I have a client/server implementation : My method hello() is called by the client periodically:

```
void ClassB::hello() {
InitFunction();
/* something to do */
}
```

In another Class I have the InitFunction which looks like:

```
void ClassA::InitFunction() {
initData();
/* other stuff */ 
}
```

The initData() Has to be called only once by thread. I want to make sure that this function is called only once (or only once InitFunction()). I'm using c++11. I've checked std::call_once but I don't think that it solves my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use thread local storage

Comment: Check and `std::call_once` and `thread_local`

Comment: Can you have each thread construct its own instance of your class?  If so, you could just put initData in the constructor or update a boolean on first use.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Singleton pattern where the Singleton is stored in TLS (thread local storage).

Actually quite a broad answer, as your question is rather broad, too. TLS is usually provided by the runtime you are using, so to get a better answer, show what you have achieved so far and tell us more about your runtime / operating system and compiler.

Comment: c++11 includes the `thread_local` keyword, so there shouldn't be any need to worry about OS/compiler-specific APIs anymore.